# Imageview over imageview (png over jpg)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, imageview

Many topics about his, but still haven't found my solution:

I'm working with Xamarin Studio: Within my launch screen I have one `view` with two `ImageViews`. The first image `.jpg` is being set to `fill parent` vertically and horizontally. The image that should go on top of the background image is a `.png` (transparent background with white lettering).

I have my `BuildAction` set to `BundleResource` and the image source of `.png` does not show the extension, just the image name. The problem is that the `.png` image is not showing up. Tried deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders and rebuilding, but without succes.

Comment: It would be also important to paste the code or XML where you are setting the ImageView sources.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Info.plist` make sure the value for `Launch Screen` is set to your LanchScreen.storyboard (might be different name for yours). Open that storyboard and place your UIImageViews in the desired order.

If you work with LaunchImages instead you need to compose your image beforehand in a picture editor.